# How can I run a post build event after app packages are created for the store in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, post-build-event

I wrote a post build script to process some of the files created when Visual Studio builds my Windows app for the Windows Store. Unfortunately, the post build event is triggered before the .appxpackage files are created. Does anyone know of a work around that would let me mvoe or copy the .appxpackage file after it is created?

- This is a C# Windows Runtime app for the Windows Store.
- I am using the menu Project/Store/Create App Packages... to do the build.

I'm looking at  but I can't figure out how to use it to run a batch file and to have various macros available in that batch file. Help would be appreciated if the after build target mechanism would work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you queueing builds via Team Explorer to be run on a build agent(s)? If so, you can 'Edit Build Definitions', select your build def, go to the Process tab, Build, Advanced, and edit prebuild info there. I have several bat files that I use in prebuild and postbuild scripts in a TFS and Visual Studio 2013 environment. Watch you build progress to see prebuild/postbuild scripts get executed. Also refer to build log.

Comment: I'm simply selecting the "Create App Package..." menu item in the Store menu in the Visual Studio IDE and the build is done locally.